# how to change spritebuilder Project name

Tags: ios, spritebuilder

i'am developing an game in xcode for iPhone ,i'am using spritebuilder ,in start i have just named it and now i want to change my sprite builder Project name .
How do I rename a spritebuilder  project ?

Answer (score 2):

Only manually at the moment:

- Close SpriteBuilder
- Open Finder, browse to the `projectname.spritebuilder` folder
- Rename the `projectname.spritebuilder` folder to, for example, `newname.spritebuilder` (keep the .spritebuilder extension!)
- inside the .spritebuilder folder, rename the following files, also keeping their extensions:

  - `projectname.approj` => `newname.approj`
  - `projectname.ccbproj` => `newname.ccbproj`
- Open the `projectname.xcodeproj` in Xcode
- Rename the project in Xcode to `newname`, the project file's name should change to `newname.xcodeproj` (if it does not, close xcode and rename it manually in Finder)

This is from the top of my head. It's possible I forgot something. Let me know if that's the case and I'll look into it.

See also: ["Rename Project" feature request](https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder/issues/1159)